# Use clipboard images to draw paths that repeat over entire length of the line

Tags: drawing, clipboard, bezier, inkscape

Using Inkscape, I have an image path created similar to below:

[image: path image used to draw from clipboard]

With this image copied to the clipboard I can then draw paths using the image, however each line I draw will 'stretch' the base image...for example:

[image: drawn stretched path]

Or...

[image]

My question is to find if there is a way to prevent the 'stretching'...?  I would like the base image copied to clipboard to 'fill' and/or 'repeat' over the entire length of the drawn line...is this possible?  To show it graphically I would like to draw line(s) where the base image repeats to cover the entire length of the drawn line, similar to this:

[image: drawn line with base image that repeats without stretching]

...Possible?  Any advice appreciated.  I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Use the 'Pattern along Path' extension or the 'Pattern along Path' path effect (< recommended, because you can modify it 'live').

Actually, that path effect is the same one as the 'from clipboard' option in the Bézier and Pencil tools, only with the 'single, stretched' option instead of 'repeated'.